# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: processing instructions must not start with xml

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing

I have this error with write and read xml file parsed.

those are function for write and read:

```
protected void write_xml_file(String file_name) {
    //if (file_name == null) file_name = "spells.xml";
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = openFileOutput(file_name, Context.MODE_APPEND);
        XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
        serializer.setOutput(fos, "UTF-8");
        serializer.startDocument(null, Boolean.valueOf(true));
        serializer.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true);
        serializer.startTag(null, "spells");
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            serializer.startTag(null, "spell");
            serializer.text("asd" +j);
            serializer.endTag(null, "spell");
        }
        serializer.endDocument();
        serializer.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

protected void read_xml_file(String file_name,Context context) {
    try {
        String path=context.getFilesDir() + File.separator + file_name;
        File fXmlFile = new File(context.getFilesDir() + File.separator + file_name);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = null;
        dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("spells");


        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

            //System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                //System.out.println("spell id : " + eElement.getAttribute("id"));
                //System.out.println("name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("firstname").item(0).getTextContent());
                //System.out.println("description : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("firstname").item(0).getTextContent());
                //System.out.println("school : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("lastname").item(0).getTextContent());

            }
        }


    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the error:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: processing instructions must not start
>   with xml (position:unknown @6:10 in java.io.InputStreamReader@b64434e)

Comment: You'll need to post your xml, looks like thats the problem, rather than the code.

Comment: my xml is write into internal storage, i don't know how to get it

Answer (score 1):

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: processing instructions must not start with xml (position:unknown @6:10 in java.io.InputStreamReader@b64434e)

It looks like you have `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` in your XML file. Remove it then try it!

Comment: is this the tag to remove?serializer.setOutput(fos, "UTF-8");

Comment: @Nevarim Yep, remove it

Answer (score 0):

This error usually happens when you load several times (at least two times) the file in the stream and then try to parse it. Check if you do not load the file two time in fXmlFile